# f.fields_for a has_many relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an assessment model which has_many answers. I'm trying to build my f.fields_for but getting an error:

```
"undefined method `content' for <Answer::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fdb12041fd8>"
```

View:

```
 <%= f.fields_for @answers do |builder| %>
   <%= builder.text_area :content, :class=>"form-control question-field", :data => {:question => question.id} %>
  <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
  def edit
    @assessment = current_user.assessments.find(params[:id])
    @answers = @assessment.answers
  end
```

I understand that the error seems to be that I'm calling methods on a collection rather than the individual object. But I don't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If `f` is a builder for `@assassment`, you can do:

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.text_area :content, :class=>"form-control question-field", :data => {:question => question.id} %>
<% end %>
```

You will also need this in your `Assassement` model:

```
class Assasement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
  #...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`#fields_for` expects an `object_name` as first parameter or an `object` – but no collection. So you have two choices, depdening on the context. Either get the child collection from the outher form helper (`f`) implicitly:

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
```

Or pass a specific collection as a second argument like so:

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers, @answers do |builder| %>
```

Specs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for